# Lubricant for Sticky Home Button on iPhone 5S?

Tags: iphone

The home button on my 5S is sticky.  It still works, if I apply extra pressure.  Is it safe to add a bit of WD-40 or some other lubricant?  Recommendations for the best lubricant to use?

Comment: Take it to a genius bar, your phone is still under warranty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be best to take your iPhone in to the Apple Store (I have had luck in the past with them replacing my iPhone when there is a hardware issue, even when I did not have an AppleCare plan for the device); however, if you are willing to risk possible (although probably unlikely) damage to the internals, you could put a small drop of rubbing alcohol on the home button and press it repeatedly until it is no longer sticky.

Answer (score 0):

To me it appears as safe but it might feel oily after that and stick dust around it ...